# Android - ActionBarSherlock - Set textcolor of text in menu

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, submenu

I want to change white color of text to orange.

Here is a example.

[image: ActionBarSherlock]

Answer (score 3):

This can be done through setting some styles for your action bar. It is explained in this blog post http://android-developers.blogspot.com.au/2011/04/customizing-action-bar.html

You need to set this in your style for you app.

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
     <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/MyDropDownListView</item>
</style>
```

Then you can specify this style with your own text color.

```
<!-- style the items within the overflow menu -->
<style name="MyDropDownListView" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.ListView.DropDown">
    <!-- This is the orange text color -->
    <item name="android:textColor">#CC3232</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Well this does actually not work for me. A DropDown Item here has only background selectors.

Comment: Works for me! I'm actually developing in Xamarin Android and I have been looking everywhere for this solution. After countless google searching I finally stumbled on this and tried it and it worked like a charm. You dont know how good it feels for that submenu to finally turn blue haha.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the color of the `MenuItem` text easily by using `SpannableString` instead of `String`.

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.your_menu, menu);

    int positionOfMenuItem = 0; // or whatever...
    MenuItem item = menu.getItem(positionOfMenuItem);
    SpannableString s = new SpannableString("My red MenuItem");
    s.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, s.length(), 0);
    item.setTitle(s);
}
```